# Как реализовать такую кнопку

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, подскажите как сделать такую кнопку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 70px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: relative;  
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background: rgba(1,177,230,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(1,177,230,1) 0%, rgba(0,122,213,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(1,177,230,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,122,213,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(1,177,230,1) 0%, rgba(0,122,213,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(1,177,230,1) 0%, rgba(0,122,213,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(1,177,230,1) 0%, rgba(0,122,213,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1,177,230,1) 0%, rgba(0,122,213,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#01b1e6', endColorstr='#007ad5', GradientType=1 );
}

.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  background: #0567aa;
}

.btn:before{
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Обратная связь</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще один пример

```css
.coolButton {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius:25px;
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:16pt;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.coolButton .secondSpan,.coolButton .firstSpan {
  position:relative;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
.coolButton .backgroundSpan {
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transform:skewX(-20deg);
  width:120%;
  height:100%;
}
.coolButton .firstSpan .backgroundSpan {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#00B0E5, #0478D2);
  right:0;
}
.coolButton .secondSpan .backgroundSpan {
  background-color:#0467A9;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='coolButton'>
  <span class='firstSpan'>
     <span class='backgroundSpan'></span>
     <span class='text'>Обратная связь</span>
  </span>
  <span class='secondSpan'>
     <span class='backgroundSpan'></span>
     <span class='text'>+</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое